# Why is the Relief algorithm slow for large numbers of observations?

Tags: r, feature-selection

I am currently working on a multi-class classification problem and have a dataset of about 130 features and 120000 observations.

Digging through literature I found the Relief feature selection method, or Relief-F as the implementation most used. The concept seems promising however the calculation time is far to long to be of use as a first selection step.

In my example I am using R and the FSelector package. One run of Relief with 10 neighbours and 20 samples takes more than five hours on current hardware. I assume that the implemention is single-threaded.

When looking at the algorithm I do not understand where this massive amount of computational effort is needed. With only 20 samples to analyse I feel this should be a lot quicker. Can anybody shed some light please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what the implementers actually did, but a naïve implementation of `relief` would require you to compute the distance from the 20 sample points to all of the 120000 data points for each of the 130 variables. This gives a total of

> 20*120000*130 = 3.12e+08

distance calculations. In your 130 dimensional space, that would require 130 multiplications and 129 additions, so you would need a total of

> 20*120000*130*(130+129) = 8.0808e+10 arithmetic operations.

I guess I am not surprised if that takes a while.

I just ran `relief` on a data set with 420 instances of 279 variables using the default of 10 samples. Using the same naïve calculation as above, I think that this should have been

> 10*420*279*(279+278) = 6.52e+8 arithmetic operations.

On my laptop, that took about 7 minutes. So my guess is that on my laptop, your calculation would take

> 8.0808e+10 /6.52e+8 * 7 = 867.6 minutes  or about 14.5 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if the algorithm works like this the long calculation time is completely understandable. I didn't realize the distance has to be calculated to all other samples in order to find the closest hits and misses.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the Relief-F implementation in the CORElearn package, I am not sure how the implementations differ, but I commonly run ReliefF using CORElearn on datasets of about 100k records and about 20 predictors without taking too much time (minutes not hours).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I can confirm that it's running significantly faster, however the results differ quite a lot to the FSelector implementation.

Comment: I can't speak to which is correct, but the CORElearn package is written by  Marko Robnik-Sikonja who is a co-author on many of the Relief papers